# Clion run and degug give different results

Tags: c, debugging, fork, clion, remote-debugging

all
I have a simple cmake project that I've created in clion (v2023.1.2 , mac M1)
For some reason I get different outputs in the debug an run mode and can't figure out why.
Please advise
this is the code

```
int main(void) {
    int status;
    sem_t *sem = sem_open(SNAME, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
    status = fork();
    if (status == 0){
        //sem_wait(sem);
        printf("2 No! it's not true! it's impossible\n");
        printf("4 Noooooooooooooo\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("1 Luke, I am your father!\n");
        printf("3 Search your feelings, you know it to be true.\n");
        printf("5 Luke, you can destroy the Emperor. He has foreseen it.\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

When running in **run** I get the output

```
Process finished with exit code 1
/tmp/fml/cmake-build-debug-docker/fml
1 Luke, I am your father!
3 Search your feelings, you know it to be true.
5 Luke, you can destroy the Emperor. He has foreseen it.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and while using **debug** I get the output

```
<home_folder>/CLionProjects/fml/cmake-build-debug-docker/fml
1 Luke, I am your father!
3 Search your feelings, you know it to be true.
5 Luke, you can destroy the Emperor. He has foreseen it.
2 No! it's not true! it's impossible
4 Noooooooooooooo

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my cmake profile
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and show also the includes and the rest of the relevant code, IOW a [mcve]

Comment: You probably have a race condition here. It can more or less be replicated here: https://onlinegdb.com/6oVTMDa_u